# Vue table does not show data

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to show data in vue table using api in api url. Basically I am doing a post request in created method that is sending an id to the server and the server is returning data associated with the id. And simply I am using the api that is returning data. Every thing looks okay but data is not showing in vue table.

**vue table**
`

```
                    <vuetable ref="vuetable"
                      api-url="http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/patient_previous_appointments"
                      :fields="fields"
                      pagination-path=""
                      :per-page="5"
                      :multi-sort="true"
                      :sort-order="sortOrder"
                      :append-params="moreParams"
                      :data = "data"
                      @vuetable:pagination-data="onPaginationData"
                    >
```

`

**data property**

`

```
 data () {
  return {
    data: [],
    fields: FieldsDef_previous_appointment,
    sortOrder: [],
    moreParams: {}
  }
}
```

`

**Fields**

`

```
 export const FieldsDef_previous_appointment = [
    {
        name:'date',
        title: 'Date',
        sortField: 'date',
        titleClass: 'center aligned',
        dataClass: 'center aligned',
    },
    {
        name:'doctor',
        title: '<i class="fa fa-tag"></i> Doctor',
        sortField: 'doctor'
    },
    {
        name:'appointed_by',
        title: '<i class="fa fa-tag"></i> Appointed By',
        sortField: 'appointed_by'
    },
    {
        name: '__slot:actions',
        title: 'Actions',
        dataClass: 'center aligned'
    }
]
```

`

**Created**

`

```
  created () {
      const tokenData = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('authUser'))
      var pt_id = tokenData.patient_id
      this.$http.get(apiDomain + 'api/patient_previous_appointments', 
      {patientID: 
       pt_id})
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
    }).catch((e) => {
      console.log(e)
    })
```

}

`

**response**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZz3l.jpg)

Comment: Please provide your `created()` as well. Have you tried manually assigning some content to your `data` array for testing if everything displays? Also, you might want to use [Vue DevTools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en) to inspect your Vue components and data.

Comment: Please see update

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting your `data` once you get the `response` from the API? Also have you tried the suggestion from my previous comment?

Comment: thanks @sykez your last suggestion worked

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: :) :) yep it worked